# When condition in android

Tags: java, android

I have an app that listens for incoming serial data from a hc 05 bluetooth module. I would like to have a situation whereby when a certain value is set via an edit text, the app compares this value with that incoming from the bluetooth module. When the value from the bluetooth module exceeds the value set by the user, the vibrator service is invoked.

```
    void beginListenForData() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; // This is the ASCII code for a newline
    // character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                 int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                        encodedBytes, 0,
                                        encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(
                                        encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        myLabel.setText(data);
                                      Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_usage);
                                        btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                                        int dt = Integer.parseInt(data);
                                                        int us = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString());
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usage set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        if (dt>us)
                                                        {
                                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Times Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                                                            vib.vibrate(2000);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    }
                                        );
                                             }});
                            }
```

The code above only invokes the vibrator service if the value set by the user is greater than that from the bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple edits, I'd advise studying... a lot. I know for a fact that this snippet of code you have used it straight out of a tutorial available online. While it is fine to use that as a base, it's going to be far too difficult for you to accomplish this task without a decent understanding of what it is that you're actually doing.

Edit::

There are going to be a lot of changes here, because you've made a lot of mistakes.

```
public class My_activity extends Activity {

    ...
    // move data, making it a member variable of your activity

    String data = null;

    ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // move your btn click code to on create
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_usage);
        btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // begin bluetooth check with newly add loop
                beginListenForData();
                // call your new checkData method
                checkData();
            }
        });  
    }
}

// create a method for checking bt data
public void checkData() {
    if (data != null && txt.getText().toString().length > 0) {
        int dt = Integer.parseInt(data);
        int us = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usage set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (dt>us) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Times Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(2000);
        }
    }
}

// edited method for checking bt data
public void beginListenForData() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; // This is the ASCII code for a newline
    // character
    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                    encodedBytes, 0,
                                    encodedBytes.length);
                                    data = new String(
                                    encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            myLabel.setText(data);
                                            checkData();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    // this is the end of your try block
                    // you didn't give me anything else to work with past this point
                    } // catch ()
```

Comment: I don't think you have understood the question. I want to check **when** one value is greater than the other.

Comment: Do you want to check when one is greater on user input instead of on a button click?

Comment: Yes i would like to do that

Comment: Thanks but that does not let me achieve what i really wanted. I would like a button that when clicked, gets the user input , does the comparison and then invokes the vibrator service.

Comment: Yes i am, but my code only triggers the vibration service **if** input from Bluetooth is greater than the the user input  (at the point of clicking the button) else the user the vibration service is not triggered at all.

Comment: Do you have loop of some sort that continually checks for updated bluetooth data?

Comment: No i don't. Kindly update your answer with a loop :)

Comment: I have to see your code for receiving the bluetooth data before I can tell you what to do with it